# Take CSV file and save it into separate MATLAB files by day

Tags: matlab, save

I am new to Matlab and I need to create .mat files for each day in the files. [link to CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxNCngJKhAn1SDVlOXczMW8xaUU&usp=sharing)

The code is below, the issues I am having is in the commented out sections. I basically need to save a separate .mat file for each day, which is stored in column 1. Thanks all.

```
clear;
Info=csvread('tester.csv');
%header=csvread('header.csv');
days=unique(Info(:,1));
numdays= length(days);
for i = 1:numdays

    %Info.header=header;

    %write headers in 
    %Info.data=Info(Info(:,1)==days(i),:);

    str = sprintf('save data%i.mat', i);
    eval(str);
end
```

Comment: Do you have tester.csv and header.csv available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
fid = fopen('tester_small.csv','r'); % // open the file
h = fgetl(fid); % // read the first line which is  the header
headers = strsplit(h,','); % // split the headers into a cell array
formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f'; % // set the format for the data
data = textscan(fid, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', ','); %//     read in the data
fclose(fid); % // close the file

Info=cell2mat(data); 
days=unique(Info(:,1));
numdays= length(days);
for cnt = 1:numdays
    % // clear the variable between each run so 
    % // that you don't include data from previous iteration
   clear S;
   S.header = headers;
   S.data=Info(Info(:,1)==days(cnt),:);
   filename = sprintf('data%i.mat', cnt);
   save(filename,'S');
end
```

---

This is `tester_small.csv` i.e. the first ten rows of your file:

```
Date,Minutes,DC114T,DCRCS103,DCRCS104,DCRCS110
40484,5,72.681519,692.999939,689.999878,559.999878
40484,10,72.681519,695.19989,693.799866,558.799927
40484,15,72.681519,693.999939,693.799866,560.999878
40484,20,72.681519,692.19989,694.999878,558.799927
40484,25,72.681519,693.19989,696.999939,558.999939
40484,30,72.681519,692.19989,699.999878,560.799927
40484,35,72.681519,690.999878,700.999878,563.999939
40484,40,72.681519,696.199951,697.999878,562.999939
40484,45,72.681519,696.199951,696.999939,564.999878
```

This is the result when loading the file.

```
load data1.mat
>> S
S =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

header =
{
  [1,1] = Date
  [1,2] = Minutes
  [1,3] = DC114T
  [1,4] = DCRCS103
  [1,5] = DCRCS104
  [1,6] = DCRCS110
}
data =

  4.0484e+004  5.0000e+000  7.2682e+001  6.9300e+002  6.9000e+002  5.6000e+002
  4.0484e+004  1.0000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9520e+002  6.9380e+002  5.5880e+002
  4.0484e+004  1.5000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9400e+002  6.9380e+002  5.6100e+002
  4.0484e+004  2.0000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9220e+002  6.9500e+002  5.5880e+002
  4.0484e+004  2.5000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9320e+002  6.9700e+002  5.5900e+002
  4.0484e+004  3.0000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9220e+002  7.0000e+002  5.6080e+002
  4.0484e+004  3.5000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9100e+002  7.0100e+002  5.6400e+002
  4.0484e+004  4.0000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9620e+002  6.9800e+002  5.6300e+002
  4.0484e+004  4.5000e+001  7.2682e+001  6.9620e+002  6.9700e+002  5.6500e+002
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with your file then because it clearly worked for me. There is nothing wrong with [`csvread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html). It's just that it takes numeric values only. Your header is not numeric. You may be able to use `csvread` if you remove the headers but I would then question why you have one file with the headers and one file with the data when you can combine them. Ultimately, you should do what is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have `.csv` files

```
header.csv
 Date,Time,Data1,Data2,...,DataN

tester.csv
 Date,Time,Data1,Data2,...,DataN
 DtNO,TiNO, D11, D12, ... ,D1N
 ...
```

Then running this code we load whole `.csv` in one array, divide it into groups by `Date` column and export it into `testdata-<Date>.mat` files.

```
Header=importdata('header.csv',',');
Testdata=importdata('tester.csv',',',1);
Date=Testdata(1,1);
EndDate=Testdata(end,1);
Advance=true;

while Advance
  %% Find the part for one Date
  Indices=find(Testdata(:,1)==Date);
  %% Pick whole data set for perticullar Date
  Data=Testdata(Indices,:);
  %% Save Data, Header and Date variables only
  save(['testdata-' Date '.mat','Data','Date','Header');
  %% Advance to next Date
    if Date~=EndDate
      Date=TestData(Indices(end),1);
    else
      Advance=false;
    end
end
```